# Stack with Cefpython3 programe

Tags: kivy-language, chromium-embedded, kivymd, cefpython

The program works very well while in my pycharm editor but if i convert the python file to apk using buildozer, the app refuses to open on mobile phone. this is the error it throws
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKR0q.png)

Comment: That is the error  (64-bit instead of 32-bit
12-31 11:22:27.332 11288 11378 I python  : Python for android ended.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.